# Error when trying to get model from categories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa

I have two models, a product model and a category model that communicate via ManyToOne and vice verse. In my category model, I have an array that receives the products and in my product model I have a "category" that references the category model.

product model

```
package com.api.business_products_management.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class ProductModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String product;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 80)
    private String desc;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private Float price;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private Number stock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryModel category;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Number getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Number stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public CategoryModel getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(CategoryModel category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

category model

```
package com.api.business_products_management.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORIES")
public class CategoryModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 80)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<ProductModel> products;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<ProductModel> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<ProductModel> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

In the category controller, my post method worked normally, but my get mode when making a request in postman, the error occurs

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.category_id,p1_0.id,p1_0.desc,p1_0.price,p1_0.product,p1_0.stock from products p1_0 where p1_0.category_id=?]]
```

here the controller

```
package com.api.business_products_management.controllers;

import com.api.business_products_management.dtos.CategoryDto;
import com.api.business_products_management.models.CategoryModel;
import com.api.business_products_management.services.CategoryService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleState;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/category")
public class CategoryController {

    final CategoryService categoryService;

    public CategoryController(CategoryService categoryService) {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveCategory (@RequestBody @Valid CategoryDto categoryDto) {
        if (categoryService.existsByName(categoryDto.getName())) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Conflict: Category already exists! ");
        }
        var categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(categoryDto, categoryModel);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(categoryService.save(categoryModel));
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<CategoryModel>> getAllCategories() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(categoryService.findAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a parameterised constructor and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Where in the code and how?

Comment: Checkout lombok library add that as dependency and use annotations AllArgsConstructor and NoArgsConstrcutor. Lombok will create that for you. This you need to do in your entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think even if you solve your problem, this type of implementation has performance and security issues!

It is incorrect to return the entire objects in our REST APIs. So, I advise you to read more about DTO Projection and using third parties like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/). Hope these links help you:

[Spring Data JPA Projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)
[Quick Guide to MapStruct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct)

Comment: Is it wrong for me to make a category request and show me all the products in it? Or is it wrong for me to make a product request and show me the category that product is associated with?

Comment: About returning all data from my api, actually I intend to implement a pagination after solving this problem