# Error storing object in "ManyToOne" value in spring boot (Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa

I have a product model with a "category" column, which references the "category" model by
@ManyToOne. When making the body request in my postman, like for example

```
{
    "product": "iPhone XL 17 64gb",
    "description": "The new iphone",
    "price": 15000.68,
    "stock": 34,
    "category": {
        "id": "afff7473-7946-4ebd-afe2-d0c118cf5df8" 
    }
}
```

a status 400 error occurs followed by the console error:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.UUID` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)]
```

I believe the problem is in the DTO of my product, but I don't know what could be done wrong

productDto

```
package com.api.business_products_management.dtos;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import java.util.UUID;

public class ProductDto {
    @NotBlank
    private String product;

    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", inclusive = true)
    private Float price;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Stock must be at least {value}")
    private Integer stock;

    @NotNull
    private UUID category;

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Integer stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public UUID getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(UUID category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

productModel

```
package com.api.business_products_management.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class ProductModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String product;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 80)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private Float price;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private Integer stock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryModel category;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Integer stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public CategoryModel getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(CategoryModel category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

categoryModel

```
package com.api.business_products_management.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORIES")
public class CategoryModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 80)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<ProductModel> products;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<ProductModel> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<ProductModel> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

categoryDto

```
package com.api.business_products_management.dtos;

import com.api.business_products_management.models.ProductModel;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CategoryDto {

    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    private List<Long> productIds;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Long> getProductIds() {
        return productIds;
    }

    public void setProductIds(List<Long> productIds) {
        this.productIds = productIds;
    }
}
```

ps: Now the product is being created, but category is "null"

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your payload.  Category is a UUID, so it needs to be sent as such.

```
{
  "product": "iPhone XL 17 64gb",
  "description": "The new iPhone",
  "price": 15000.68,
  "stock": 34,
  "category": "afff7473-7946-4ebd-afe2-d0c118cf5df8" 
}
```

Also, just a side note.  You're using a Float to represent what looks like monetary values.  Do not do this; you're going to run into issues the more you add, subtract, multiply, and divide this value.  Instead, use BigDecimal for these values.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that way and it didn't work before... I tried to do as the other user suggested and got a status 201, however, my category is "null"

Answer (score 0):

Category should be an object dto, not a UUID. For example:

```
public class CategoryDto {
    
private UUID id;
    
    //getter setter
    }
```

And the ProductDto obiect would have

```
public class ProductDto {

// rest of the fields 

private CategoryDto category;

}
```

Comment: Now it gave status 201, but in my "category" when creating the product it is null and not the category that I used the id

Comment: {
    "id": "61fea67c-44c7-4deb-aee4-2029847d0c02",
    "product": "iPhone XL 17 64gb",
    "description": "iphone",
    "price": 15000.68,
    "stock": 34,
    "category": null
}

Comment: well, post the code snippet where you save it in the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75511846/error-when-trying-to-get-model-from-categories?noredirect=1#comment133236248_75511846

Comment: Here the link...